# Colocar fila a columna dinámico sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Amigos,
tengo un inconveniente si me puedan ayudar , lo que deseo es que la fila este como columna dinámico, tengo una tabla que tiene un ORD ese campo es segun el orden de la fecha

```
create table #temp3
(
ORD INT null,
HFECPRO DATE NULL,
HNOMBREPTO VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
HVALORTX FLOAT NULL,
HNUMEROTX FLOAT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(1,'2021-04-17','B&M',888.00,4)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(1,'2021-04-17','BAZAR FANNY',1358.00,3)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(1,'2021-04-17','AGENTE PAGA FACIL',7400.00,21)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(2,'2021-04-19','AGENTE PAGA FACIL',2222.00,10)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(2,'2021-04-19','BAZAR FANNY',1000.00,30)
INSERT INTO #temp3 VALUES(2,'2021-04-19','AGENTE PAGA FACIL',3005.00,90)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que se muestre asì

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estuve avanzando con el pivot pero no llego a lo que quiero**

```
declare @cols varchar(max),@query nvarchar(max)
select @cols=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.hfecpro)                                           
       FROM #temp3 c                                         
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE                                          
       ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                                           
      ,1,1,'')     

set @query = 'SELECT HNOMBREPTO,HNUMEROTX, ' + @cols + ' from                                           
       (                                        
     select HFECPRO,HNOMBREPTO,HVALORTX,HNUMEROTX                        
     from #temp3                                        
      ) x                                          
       pivot                                           
       (                                    
      SUM(HVALORTX)                                          
     for HFECPRO in (' + @cols + ')                                          
       ) p'   

        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @query
```

Comment: @JuanRivera verdad ahora le coloco

Comment: @JuanRivera muchas gracias, ya lo modifique y lo agregue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cambies de PIVOT al uso de agregados condicionales que darán un mejor rendimiento al transponer múltiples columnas que requerirían de múltiples PIVOT. También da mucha mayor flexibilidad al momento de definir las columnas (diversas operaciones, rangos, etc.)

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max);

--Primero ponemos las columnas sobre las cuales agruparemos
SET @Query = N'SELECT HNOMBREPTO ' + NCHAR(10) 
--Después colocamos las columnas que vamos a transponer
+ ( SELECT REPLACE( N',MAX( CASE WHEN ORD = <<ORD>> THEN HVALORTX END) AS HVALORTX<<ORD>>
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN ORD = <<ORD>> THEN HNUMEROTX END) AS HNUMEROTX<<ORD>>', N'<<ORD>>', ORD)+ NCHAR(10)
    FROM #temp3
    --Eliminamos duplicados usando GROUP BY
    GROUP BY ORD
    --Definimos el orden de las columnas
    ORDER BY ORD
    --Usamos esta instrucción para concatenar los valores
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')
--Ponemos el resto de la consulta
+ N'FROM #temp3
GROUP BY HNOMBREPTO;'

--Esto es para fines de debugging
PRINT @Query

--Ejecutamos el código dinámico
EXEC sp_Executesql @Query;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias , no sabia como hacerlo , Amigo una consulta ese resultado se puede obtener solo las cabeceras dinamicas?

Comment: A que te refieres con solo las cabeceras dinámicas?

Comment: que me recomiendas quiero mejorar mis consultas en sql server

Comment: que me recomiendas quiero mejorar mis consultas en sql